# French requirements for breathalysers in cars

Tags: france, legal, driving

I noticed that UK retailer sell packs of breathalysers for motorists intending to drive cars to France.

An [RAC web-page](http://www.rac.co.uk/driving-abroad/france) says

> While driving in France you are required by law to carry the following items. Hefty on-the-spot fines can be issued for failing to carry specific items:
>
> ...
>
> Breathalysers/alcohol test (As of January 2013 the French government announced that the introduction of an €11 fine has been postponed indefinitely)

Another website says

> Since April 2013, carrying a brethalyzer with you in the car has been obligatory in France... by law - at least in theory. BUT this is a wonderful law that you are free to observe or not observe, as there is no penalty for drivers caught without a brethalyzer in their car.
>
> Single-use certified breathalyzers are now available in many supermarkets, chemists and garages throughout France, at a cost of about 1 €uro each. So the cost is minimal.
>
> Contrary to information posted on some sites, the new law (Decree no 2012-284) does not oblige drivers to self-test after having a drink. But those who plan to self-test to be on the safe side should have at least two breathalyzers in the car, if not more.

So **what does French law actually require**?

- Do drivers visiting France need to obtain and carry these?
- What are drivers expected to do with them, if anything?
- What exactly happens if you are stopped by French police and found not to have them.
- What happens if you are stopped by police on an autoroute, required to use one of your two single-use breathalysers and left without two breathalysers? Do you call a taxi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this official webpage](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F19459.xhtml), the list of mandatory accessory in a car in France is :

- a reflecting jacket
- a security triangle
- a breathalyser

Nevertheless, it is also explicitly mentioned that the lack of a breathalyser isn't submitted to a penalty. You are therefore actually not required to have one in your car.

You can be submitted to an alcohol test on the police's own breathalyser, or to a blood analysis.

Don't drink and drive !

Comment: I'll add that the police probably can't fine you with your own breathanalyzer since they don't know if it's even legit so they'll use their own. 

Also I think they dropped the idea of making a sanction because of how useless the idea is. 

If you want peace of mind, just buy two, throw them in the car, and forget about them.